# Different scripts communicating too late

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject target;
private Rigidbody2D targetRB2D;
private Rigidbody targetRB;

private void Push()
{
    SwitchKinematic();

    direction = -arrow.direction;
    float amount = Mathf.Clamp((ForceAmount(force) * distance), 0f, 50000f);

    if (target.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
    {
        targetRB2D.AddForce(amount * direction, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
    if (target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
    {
        targetRB.AddForce(amount * direction, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    StartCoroutine(AttackSwitch());
}

private void Pull()
{
    SwitchKinematic();

    direction = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    direction = direction.normalized;
    float amount = Mathf.Clamp(-ForceAmount(force), -20000f, 20000f);

    if (target.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
    {
        targetRB2D.AddForce(amount * direction, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
    if (target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
    {
        targetRB.AddForce(amount * direction, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}

private void SwitchKinematic()
{
    if (target.GetComponent<InteractiveObjectType>() != null)
    {
        if (target.GetComponent<InteractiveObjectType>().stopped)
        {
            target.GetComponent<InteractiveObjectType>().stopped = false;
        }
    }
}
```

- `Push()` is happening on *Mouse0 input up*
- `Pull()` is happening on *Mouse1 input held*

I have two scripts communicating with each other which switch `Rigidbody.Iskinematic` on and off via boolean check on one side. This method above is the one telling the other one's rigidbody to become Dynamic while it's Kinematic.

This is working fine as it should(have checked through debugger showing lines happening in order), but my problem here is while `Push()` 's commands are operating in order as it should the other script receiving this method's boolean toggle seems too *late*. Therefore those lines are happening already while `SwitchKinematic()` didn't affect the other code to toggle its boolean yet.

My understanding is that this is due to the timing of commands happening since they are separate scripts, but not sure how to resolve this. I've also included a similar method in the script; `Pull()`. `Pull()` is successfully switching the receiving end's boolean and bodytype without problem since it's updated every frame, but `Push()` only happens on `KeyUp` and I need it to be kept that way.

Comment: In Update, does the call for `Pull` come before or after the check for `KeyUp`? Also are `Push` and `Pull` in separate scripts?

Comment: @MattL. Pull() is called by Mouse1 input held and Push() is called by Mouse0 up. I don't think the update order was it, but for your answer: Pull() 's call comes before. That's a good note, I'll edit in post to mention that difference

Comment: Ok, and the issue is that other scripts are executing their code before `Push` calls `SwitchKinematic` right? If so, try checking out this link on defining the order in which scripts are executed https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html

Comment: @MattL. The issue is the other script needs to happen 2nd in order while this script's SwitchKinematic() is 1st and Push() is 3rd. Thanks for the kind link! I'll check it out now.

Comment: @MattL.Unfortunately, tweaking ScriptExecution order didn't do the trick. My only guess is how the methods are spread as they are. I'm still not sure how better to organize them.